# Django - django-select2 doesn t work with inlineformset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-select2

I`ve made a inlineformset which contains a django-select2 field. The problem appears when I try to add another inline .The select2 data don't work on cloned field.

This is my template:

```
{{ form_m.management_form }}
  {% for m in form_m.forms %}
   <div class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
        {{ m.id }}
          {{ m.medicament }}     
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{ m.cantitate }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{ m.nr_zile }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{ m.mod_administrare }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        {{ m.schema }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

This is  my script for clone fields:

```
{% load static %}

        <script src="{% static 'style/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.formset_row').formset({
                addText: '<button id="add_more" class="btn btn-sm btn-success float-right mr-1">Adauga medicamentatie</button>',
                deleteText: '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right mr-5">Elimina</button>',
                prefix: 'form_m_set',
            });
        </script>
```